# How I can handle unexpected errors in golang http server

Tags: go

This is simple http server in golang.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to my website!")
    })

    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/"))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))

    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

My question is this, why when i put `%` to url. Go server cause `400 Bad Request` error

Example:

```
http://localhost:80/anythink%
```

[image]

When someone request bad link like this in go http server, cause security information leak. if smart enough detect server side type. The main question is this to how to handle this error

Comment: The percent sign (`%`) has special meaning in `URL`, it is used to encode special/ reserved characters ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)). If you want to use a percent character in a `URL`, it must be encoded as `%25`. Thus the `URL` should be `http://localhost:80/anythink%25`...

Comment: Yes sir, understand. That's want all is handle this with custom message if cause.